# How can I trigger a click event when I click on a button that's displayed outside of my dialog element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dialog

I'm using the native HTML dialog element as a modal in my Vue 3 app and I've successfully displayed a button to the side/outside of the modal by using absolute positioning. However, due to the nature of dialog elements and how they're placed in the top layer, I'm unable to trigger a click event (displayNextModal) when I click on the button outside of the dialog element. Adjusting the z-index of either element doesn't have an effect as the dialog is always on the top layer by default. I'm wondering if there are any workarounds to this or if the only way to trigger this click event is if I put the button inside of the dialog element.

```
<template>
  <dialog class="modal-post" ref="postModalRef">
    <div>Modal screen</div>
  </dialog>
  <button class="next-modal-button" @click="displayNextModal">Next</button>
</template>
```

```
.modal-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}

.next-modal-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: if you're triggering it with `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()` then you'll need to put the button inside the dialog to interact with it. *'The showModal() method ... displays the dialog as a modal, over the top of any other dialogs that might be present. ... interaction outside the dialog is blocked and the content outside it is rendered inert.'*

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not place the button in the exact spot you want, you can always set the dialog's border and background to transparent. Then have a div inside of there that you style to look like a dialog. And have the button inside the dialog itself. That will make the button look like its outside of the dialog and still give you access to it. And you will need to mess with the sizes and absolute positioning though.

```js
const favDialog = document.querySelector('.modal-post');
const showButton = document.querySelector('#showButton');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-modal-button');


showButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    favDialog.showModal();
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("NEXT");
});
```

```css
.modal-post {
  border:0;
  background:transparent;
  height:100%
}

.next-modal-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.modal-body{
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<dialog class="modal-post" ref="postModalRef">
    <div class="modal-body">Modal screen</div>
    <button class="next-modal-button" @click="displayNextModal">Next</button>
  </dialog>  
  <button id="showButton">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button inside the modal and position it from there. Make the parent relatively positioned then fine tune `top` and `right` values to get it where you want. No need to change anything else on the dialog class except position:

```
.modal-post {
  position: relative;
  /* … */
}
```